# How do I create a macro to scan my phone screen for a specific color (Black and white) and then depending on the color click on the left/right side

Tags: macrodroid

I'm using the mobile app Macrodroid and I am having difficulty creating a macro that scans a specific part of the phone screen (the middle of the screen) for either the color black or white. Then if it returns that the color is black than I want it to click on the left side of the screen, but if it returns as the color white then I want it to click on the right side of the screen.

I've thought of ways that it can do it for example taking a screenshot and than looking at that for the color, and I even found a plugin that can sort of do that, but I am unable to get it to work properly/know how to set it up. The plugin is called TouchTask.

Comment: See https://www.macrodroidforum.com/index.php?threads/pixel-color-detector-pixel-scan.1704/